# Axis version 1.4.1 deploy on IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: java, websphere

I'm working on a migration of applications from WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5. These applications use axis version 1.4.1 but when they are deployed in WAS 8.5 an Axis servlet error ocurrs:

```
WarBasedAxisC E org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator <init> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException                                      org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
```

and

```
webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
```

I have this link from an IBM workaround.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&q1=axis2&q2=technote&uid=swg21315686&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&cc=us&lang=en

I performed steps one, two and three. But when I try to load the application on WAS 8.5, it fails with the following error:

```
The following exception occurred. Check log for details. 
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml]
```

I have searched for other solutions, but without luck...

Has some one stumble with this issue and solved it??

Thanks.

Edit: I solved this error by rebuilding the application with the added jars. But I still get Axis exceptions at starup...

E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher incompatible with org.apache.axis2.engine.Handler

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this link should help you resolve your issue on the axis2 version. If you want to use your version of AXIS then you will need to disable the internal processor: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html .

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already solved my first question by rebuilding the EAR file. Now, after the workaround your link provide I get this:                                        com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher incompatible with org.apache.axis2.engine.Handler